# Adding a plot to a matplotlib table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I have the following table:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(16,16))
ax.axis('off')
nrows= 6
ncols=3
table = ax.table(cellText=[['']*ncols]*nrows,loc='top', rowLoc='center',colLoc='center')


for j,text in zip(range(3),['Group','Chart','Comments']):
    table[(0,j)].get_text().set_text(text)


for i,text in zip(range(1,nrows),list('ABCDE')):
    table[(i,0)].get_text().set_text(text)



for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        table[(i,j)].set_height(0.2)
        table[(i,j)]._loc = 'center'
        table[(i,j)].set_fontsize(16)
```

I am trying to add a line chart to the middle column (Chart)
[image]

for this example, the line can be just a diagonal

```
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
```

any ideas?

Comment: I guess it would be easier to use a grid spec (e.g. `plt.subplots(6, 3)`), plot the charts as usual and use `text` to plot the table cells in the outer columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Stef's comment, this would probably be easier using `GridSpec` and subplots. But for the sake of documenting this workaround:

You could use an inset axis inside the existing Table's axis. You would just have to find the `xy` location of the cell in which you want to plot them and their width/height.

You could add this to your code:

```
plt.draw()
for r in range(1, nrows):
    x0, y0, w, h = (*table[r, 1].get_xy(), table[r, 1].get_width()*.8, table[r, 1].get_height()*.8)
    axpl = ax.inset_axes(bounds=(x0+0.2*w, y0+0.2*h, w, h))
    axpl.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
```

I decreased the inset axis size to fit in the cell.

Not that I used `plt.draw()` before the call so that the `table[i,j].xy` get populated correctly.

[image]